# ionic framework animate tab switches

Tags: animation, ionic-framework

I'm trying to achieve a tab animation such as the one in this example:

http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/IAjoL

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    ....

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar animation="nav-title-slide-ios7" 
                 type="bar-positive" 
                 back-button-type="button-icon" 
                 back-button-icon="ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

    ........
  </body>
</html>
```

but if i try this using the includes of the current version 1.0.0 it does not work.
Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm running into the exact same issue using v1.1.0 and can't figure it out :p

Comment: Nope, it seems that they have removed the feature from their framework..

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this yesterday: http://ionicmaterial.com/ and find it quite cool. Take a look, you may find it useful - ping back if indeed you do.